# Return html as string from rendered/processed Razor Page in Class Library in Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a solution with a few projects, where one of them is an Azure Function App, which calls a method in a .Net Core Class Library that is responsible for generating HTML that I can use with the IronPdf library to generate a PDF file.
The HTML consists a a lot of tables, which can vary in number of rows, values and so on, which the Class Library method will make sure shows as expected.

The problem I am having is that I would like to utilize Razor Pages to generate the HTML from templates, so that I can reuse HTML snippets and put logic inside the HTML.

I have looked for ways to render a Razor Page to a string and the most promising approaches I have found requires Dependecy Injection and more importantly a context.
These are the articles I have found (They show the same solution to the problem):

1. https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/render-partial-to-string
2. https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/332/rendering-a-partial-to-a-string-in-razor-pages

As I understand it, they only work if they live in a Web App. I want all the "rendering" to happen solely in the Class Library.

What I would like to have is:

1. Create an instance of a model with some properties.
2. Render a Razor Page (or Partial) with the values from the instance.

I don't understand why this have to be so difficult, or why I need Dependency Injection, several providers, an injected View Engine and an action context.
Why can't I simply just have a method where I just say: "Please take these values and use them for the variables inside this .cshtml file, solve it, and give me back the result as a string".

I am looking for solutions for .Net Core 3, and any guidance or links to material that shows a solution or an explanation on the complexity is very welcome.

Regards, Matthias

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like it tries to do what I am trying to accomplish, but it feels way overkill. Also, the readme file is extremely confusing.

Comment: I agree, it's intimidating for absolutely no reason lol, i would recommand some medium.com tutorials/resources which will get to the point and practically use it, you can find some with a simple search if you chose to use it.

Comment: Did you check [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) ? It has better documentation for sure and way less dependencies but could be outdated (last commit is a year old).

Comment: Isn't RazorEngine what is being used in the examples I provided?
I can try look at medium.com and see if anyone can help there :) Thanks.